# Working with Akka streams, how can I group by strings that contain different values?

Tags: scala, csv, akka, akka-stream

Let me clarify my question a bit:

Here is my code

```
def averagePerAttributeFlow[T] = Flow[T]
.groupBy(10000, {
  case User(id, location, age) =>
    location match {
      case Location(city,state,country) =>
        println("MATCHING BY CITY")
        city+state+country
      case Location("n/a",state,country) =>
        println("MATCHING BY STATE")
        state+country
    }
  case UserBookRating(userId, bookISBN, rating) => userId
})
```

I have data flowing from a csv file. The format of some lines is like this:

"chicago, illinois, usa"

However some lines are like this:

" , illinois, usa"

Some lines even have garbage data for cities:

"###, illinois, usa"

How can I group by all the strings that contain illinois, usa and disregard wether the city is provided or not?

When the user types "chicago, illinois, usa" the grouping works, but when the user types "n/a, illinois, usa" the grouping does not work.
n/a means user does not care about city

EDIT:

Okay, so I figured out that it might be my filtering flow that is not working as I expected. Here is the code:

```
def filterByAttributeFlow[T](attr: String) = Flow[T].filter( {
  case user: User =>
    val attrSplit = attr.split(",").map(_.trim())
    attrSplit match {
      case Array(city,state,country) =>
        user.location.isCity(city, state, country) // check if location matches
      case Array(_,state,country) =>
        println("Filtering by State")
        user.location.isState(state,country)
    }
  case bookRating: UserBookRating =>
    bookRating.userId.contentEquals(attr) // check if userId matches
    }).withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy {
      e: Throwable =>
        system.log.error(s"Error filtering ratings by '$attr': {}", e)
        Supervision.Resume // skips the erroneous data and resumes the stream
    })
```

How can I filter and keep all the data entries that contain illinois,usa even if the city is not provided or is filled with garbage data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to switch the two cases in the filter flow and change _ to "n/a"... I guess I just needed to talk to a "rubber duck" :]